# Как показать начальные данные в Algolia autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, search, autocomplete, algolia

Использую библиотеку autocomplete от Algolia.
Данные приходят с нашего API. (сам сервис algolia не используем)

Как сделать чтоб когда поле для поиска получает фокус показывались некоторые результаты по умолчанию?

пробовал вот такой вариант:

```
onStateChange({ state, setQuery, setIsOpen, refresh }) {
        if (!state.query) {
            this.getSources({ query: '' })
        }
    }
```

и запрос на получение данных срабатывает, данные приходят но не показываются

пробовал `setIsOpen(true)` и открывается блок где должны быть подсказки, но он пустой